# Building Charts in ASP.NET MVC4 C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

I have data within a database, and wish to display them in a chart on my website. I may wish to make this chart interactive in the future including drilldown etc.

I am still at the early stages of building this and am experimenting at the moment, however I cannot find any useful resource to build a chart programatically.

At present, I have a ChartsController

```
public ActionResult GoldFixes()
    {
        Chart chart = new Chart(300, 400);
        chart.DataBindTable(db.Gfxs.Take(5));
        return View(chart);
    }
```

but I don't want it to return a View, I want a chart - e.g. to display a dashboard!

The chart can be an image, but it definitely needs to be accessible. So for the interactivity, I will need NO FLASH or anything. Just MVC4.

Problem Solved - I am using GOOGLE CHARTS!!! https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Comment: Please ignore this question. I have just solved my problem... GoogleCharts saves a LOT of HEADACHE!!! [link](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart